# Laravel 8 GET request UrlGenerationException Missing

Tags: laravel, routes, get, laravel-blade

I am having an error in sending an id for GET request in Laravel 8.

**Route code:**

```
Route::get('reports_gen',[BaseController::class, 'reports_gen'])->name('reports_gen'); 
Route::get('downloadCSV/{id}', [BaseController::class, 'downloadCSV'])->name('downloadCSV');
```

**Blade code:**

```
<li><a href="{{route('downloadCSV',$id)}}" >G1</a></li>
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function downloadCSV(Request $req,$id)
{
    echo $id;die();
}
public function reports_gen(Request $req)
{
    //dd($req);
    $id=1;
    return view("reports_generate",compact('id'));
}
```

**The error message is:**

> Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException Missing required
> parameter for [Route: downloadCSV] [URI: downloadCSV/{id}] [Missing
> parameter: id]. (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\lrvl\studentprojectapp\resources\views\reports_generate.blade.php)

I need to pass the $id parameter to the downloadCSV controller and would also want to know if there are any better ways of doing this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your route is not pointing to the controller method you are showing. Perhaps `[BaseController::class, 'downloadCSV']` should be `[BaseController::class, 'reports_gen']`

Answer (score 1):

The error msg means that you have to pass parameters as associative array, it's a "classical error" in Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes

in you blade file

```
<a href="{{ route('downloadCSV',['id' => $id]) }}">G1</a>
```

Then as *@porloscerrosΨ* wrote in comment, you have to correct your controller function.

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually due a very simple mistake.

the code was all fine.
I had the below lines in my blade as well.

```
<li><a href="{{route('downloadCSV',$id)}}">G1</a></li>               
<li><form action="{{route('downloadCSV')}}">G2</form></li>
<li><form action="{{route('downloadCSV')}}">G3</form></li>
```

The error was occuring for G2, G3's route. I forgot to change them cuz i was testing G1.